# Internationalization in django with non-english source language

Tags: django, internationalization, translation

I have a quick question regarding translation in django.

I am planing to redesign an existing company website from the ground up, this site is served in Danish (da-dk) with the option to switch to English. And i want a similar setup for my django site, ive read through the internationalization documentation a few times. But i am still left with one question:

How do i tell django that my translation strings are written in Danish?

My guess would be to use LANGUAGE_CODE='da-dk', but the django documentation is fuzzy at best as to how one should do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django uses the GNU gettext library.

Django has a django/conf/locale/en, even if English is the base transation language.

GNU gettext does not care which the base language is; English is a good choice because it is easier to find someone that translates from English to Portuguese than from Danish to Portuguese. Your en/LC_MESSAGES/*.po file will have:

```
msgid "nogle danske sætning"
msgstr "some Danish phrase"
```

and your da_dk/LC_MESSAGES/*.po file will have:

```
msgid "nogle danske sætning"
msgstr ""
```

Comment: That makes sense, so i just use django-admin.py makemessages to generate translation files for da and en. But then only translate the en version. The part of a en locale just went over my head. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: "GNU gettext does not care which the base language is": unfortunately, you are wrong https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?49598

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you will have problems with non-English default language and you can't even fix them in Django as the problem is in `gettext` and developers there refuse to support non-English default languages: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?49598